# ClientBundles and Resources: what are they and why use them? What problems do they solve?

Tags: java, gwt, clientbundle, cssresource

I am brand new too GWT, and no matter how much I read the [official doc on `ClientBundle`s](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle) I just can't seem to wrap my head around what they are, and what they do. The same goes for `CssResource`, `DataResource`, `TextResource`, `GWTCreateResource`, etc.

I *think* they exist as some kind of performance optimization for static files (such as CSS, JavaScript, or some static data source like a JSON file). Apparently, they are also "injectable", which doesn't make sense to me if they are supposed to be static CSS/JS/JSON/etc. files...

So I ask: can someone please give me a down-to-earth, simple, King's English, simple, explanation of what these objects are, and how they're used? Could I be so bold as to ask for a working example of this injection in action (the code snippet in the link above talks about injection but never actually shows it!)? How do these map to the actual files (`my-styles.css`, `dataTable-static-data.json`, etc.)? In fact, I think that's my biggest mental hurdle: tying these Java objects to the static files they represent.

Also, why bundle? Reusability across other projects? Maybe that's where the injectability comes into play? I'm so confused.

Comment: The _injection_ the doc talks about is the fact that your CSS lives as a String until you _inject_ it into the document as a stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They solve lots of problems:

1. Your CSS is compile-safe. If you use a css-class, that does not exist, the compile will show you which class does not exist
2. Your CSS is name-safe. If you have two different widgets, which uses the same css-classname, the compiler ensures, that your widget "A" class does not corrupt the widget "B" css
3. You compile images automatic into data-url or sprite images. This will reduce tghe amount of http-calls.

Take a look at the goals: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle